# Treeview created at runtime not displaying nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have two treeview controls, one is manually added at design time and the other is created at runtime. The string `ParentNode` should be displayed on both sides of the panels but it's not displaying on the treeview created at runtime. I'm not sure if it's something basic I'm missing or if the custom control Accordion is the problem.

Why is `runTimecustomTreeView` not displaying the node?

[image]

Code:

```
using ExpanderApp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CustomTreeView runTimecustomTreeView = new CustomTreeView();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateAccordion();
            BuildTreeViewTest1();
            BuildTreeViewTest2();
        }

        private void BuildTreeViewTest1()
        {
            //Control Added design time
            customTreeView1.Nodes.Add("ParentNode");
        }

        private void BuildTreeViewTest2()
        {
            //Control Added run time
            runTimecustomTreeView.Nodes.Add("ParentNode");
        }

        private void CreateAccordion()
        {
            Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
            accordion.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Expander expander1 = new Expander();
            expander1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            ExpanderHelper.CreateLabelHeader(expander1, "Navigation", SystemColors.ActiveBorder);
            runTimecustomTreeView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            expander1.Controls.Add(runTimecustomTreeView);
            accordion.Add(expander1);

            splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(accordion);
        }


        private void CreateContentLabel(Expander expander, string text, int height)
        {
            Label labelContent = new Label();
            labelContent.Text = text;
            labelContent.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(expander.Width, height);
            expander.Content = labelContent;
        }
    }


    //Treeview subclass to prevent double clicking checkboxes
    class CustomTreeView : TreeView
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            // Filter WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
            if (m.Msg != 0x203) base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really looks like that "Navigation" banner (whatever it is) is overlapping your tree control and that's why you can't see the node. With that said, the first thing I'd try is delete that thing just in case.

Comment: Ah thanks, it is hidden under the label! Dock is not docking where I thought it was. Add it as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Sometimes 4 tired eyes see more than 2 :). I've detected the bug because it happened so many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
runTimecustomTreeView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

With

```
runTimecustomTreeView.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
```

And you will immediately see what the bug is. Your accordion control isn't taking into account its child controls and just puts stuff over them.